# What parts are these (showerhead)?

Tags: part-identification

Just trying to identify all the metallic colored parts here and the gray one at the top... assuming they are LEGO:

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe that this is [65578](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=65578&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Posing%20Stand,%20Bar%20with%20Hollow%20Stud&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D#T=C) attached to an [angled lightsaber hilt](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x156&name=Minifigure,%20Weapon%20Lightsaber%20Hilt%20Angled&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Weapon%5D#T=C) and a [light reflector dish](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=x85&in=S).

[image: 65578]

[image: lightsaber hilt angled]

[image: reflector photo]

Comment: Thanks.  I had no clue what they were and was using all the wrong search terms attempting to figure them out on bricklink.